# Android Soft Keyboard not coming normal

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Following is the snap shot of my mobile can any one tell me how to remove the last row in the red rectangle or it is normal.

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a setting of your keyboard installed. Check the keyboard settings in the notification or in the preferences and disable "Show cursors".

Comment: Please Accept the answer if that satisfies your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Absolutely normal, It is device specific. If you run your code in any other device then the Layout of  keyboard may vary.

Comment: yep, this is the HTC Sense keyboard. Also these buttons are pretty useful.